# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried many different ways to fix this error, but it failed.
Could you fix this error?

p.s.

1. formatted_url --> There's a problem that comma turns %2c when it calls request, and this way works.

   https://opendart.fss.or.kr/api/fnlttMultiAcnt.json?crtfc_key=cd155118bef391723b04f8879878921476a97b9f&corp_code=01015160,00288495,00365590,01035678,00625942,00287812,00220622,00173351,00186559,00476036,00899556&bsns_year=2020&reprt_code=11013
2. request post --> params text is really long, and request get method occurs 414 error, so I changed it to post.
3. print(resp) :

   <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fb822c79ee0>
4. params.items() :

   dict_items([('crtfc_key', 'cd155118bef391723b04f8879878921476a97b9f'), ('corp_code', '00260985,...........00173351,00186559,00476036,00899556'), ('bsns_year', '2020'), ('reprt_code', '11013')])
5. error message

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQNQj.jpg)

```
def convertFnltt(url, items, item_names, params): 
  
  formatted_url = url + '?' + '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k,v) for k,v in params.items()])

  print(formatted_url)
  http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())
  resp = http.request('POST',formatted_url)
  print(resp)
  print('1')
  json_dict = json.load(resp) <--here!!
  print('2')
  data = []
  #if self.get_status(json_dict['status']):
  print(json_dict['status'])
  if json_dict['status']=='000':
   for line in json_dict['list']:
     data.append([])
     for itm in items:
      if itm in line.keys(): 
        data[-1].append(line[itm]) 
      else: 
        data[-1].append('')
  else:
    return json_dict['status']  
  
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
  df.columns = item_names     
  return df #df.to_excel('data.xlsx')


1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(get_fnlttMultiAcnt(crtfc_key, get_corpcode(crtfc_key), bsns_year, reprt_code))
  File "main.py", line 103, in get_fnlttMultiAcnt
    return convertFnltt(url,items,item_names,params)
  File "main.py", line 61, in convertFnltt
    json_dict = json.load(resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: resp = requests.post(formatted_url)
  print(resp) --> <Response [200]>
  json_dict = json.load(json.dumps(resp)) --> TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

Comment: resp = requests.post(formatted_url) json_dict = json.loads(resp.text) -->json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) same error occured. @snakecharmerb

Comment: What do you get if you print resp.content?

Comment: TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable @snakecharmerb

Comment: Like this `print(resp.content)`...

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue of the format of 'params'.
I used 'append' to make 'params', which caused a series of problems.
I changed 'append' to 'extend' , and it worked.

```
res = requests.get(url, params) <---'params format issue'
  json_dict = json.loads(res.text) 
  data = [] 
  
  for line in json_dict["list"]: 
    data.append([]) 
    for itm in items:
      if itm in line.keys():
        data[-1].append(line[itm])
      else: 
        data[-1].append('')

  dfp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = item_names)
```